# flask-login logout AnonymousUserMixin error

Tags: python, flask-login

I define MembershipUsers class based on UserMixin class of flask-login.

```
class MembershipUsers(UserMixin):
    applicationid = None
    userid = None
    password = None

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.userid)
```

And login process below :

```
def login_membership(userid, password):

    login_result, membership_users = _service.login(userid, password)

    if login_result == LOGIN_RESULT.OK:
        logged_in = login_user(membership_users)
```

`_service.login` is a method to login and create MembershipUsers instance. If login_result is OK, call login_user() of flask-login.

And logout below:

```
def logout_membership():
    logout_user()
```

Login is ok. But logout_user give the error:

```
'AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'userid'
```

why raise this error? Why AnonymousUserMixin?

Comment: Seems like it can only mean logout_membership() is being invoked by a function that isn't registered with the flask.ext.login.login_required decorator.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because the current user is not logged in.
As @IcarianComplex pointed out, the logout method that is `logout_membership()` doesn't have a `@login_required` decorator. If you want to do the check internally, then use

```
if current_user.is_authenticated:
     logout_user()
```